# Mongoose find elements with value in subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

**My models**

```
ActivityLanguage
language_id: ID
name: String

Activity
price: Int
languages: [ActivityLanguage]
```

what i want to do is to find the Activities that have an ActivityLanguage with certain language_id.

**This works like i need (in mongo)**:

```
db.activities.find({"languages.language_id": "59640de1675c1481820a543e" }, {"languages.$": 1})
```

How can i achieve it in mongoose?

**I already tried using:**

```
Activity.find({'languages.language_id': language_id})
```

and

```
Activity.find({"languages": {$elemMatch: { language_id: language_id }}})
```

both of them return an empty array (i already triple checked my database that there are Activities with that condition). I also tried all the answers i found here in StackOverflow without success

**How can i achieve it in mongoose?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongoose [model.populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

From your example:

```
Activity.
  find({}).
  populate({
    path: 'languages',
    model: 'ActivityLanguage',
    match: { language_id: ID }  //here you define your language_id criteria
  }).
  exec()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't worked. after many hours trying, i couldn't solve the error that appeared from your solution: "cast to objectid failed for value [ActivityLanguage stringified] at path _id for model ActivityLanguage"

Comment: Try using  `findOne` or `findById`, they are not working the same as `find` or try to use some crieriria in find. Maybe its because you recieving multiple documents. Also if you are using Mongoose you have to define a schema for your model. Have you done that?